# How to get value of selected checked boxes which are created programatically in android

Tags: android, eclipse, tags, android-checkbox

Code which i hv used to create the checkboxes

```
try{
for (int i = 0; i < Utstyr.size(); i++) {
cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
cb.setText(""+Utstyr.get(i));
cb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
cb.setTag(""+list_sted.get(i));
cb.setTextAppearance(getBaseContext(), android.R.attr.checkboxStyle);
checkbox_lay.addView(cb);
}}
catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println("ohh i got busted...!!!");
}
```

How to get the value of which checkbox is being selected.. i want h name of the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CheckBox[] chkArray = new CheckBox[Utstyr.size()];//
for (int i = 0; i < Utstyr.size(); i++) {
    chkArray[i] = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
    chkArray[i].setText(""+Utstyr.get(i));
    chkArray[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    chkArray[i].setTag(""+Utstyr.get(i));
    chkArray[i].setTextAppearance(getBaseContext(), android.R.attr.checkboxStyle);
    checkbox_lay.addView(chkArray[i]);
}
for (int k = 0; k < Utstyr.size(); k++){
    if(chkArray[k].isChecked()){
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: See my edit. Not saying its the exact reason but it might be a reason.

Comment: if(chkArray[k].isChecked()==true) gives java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @ManishYadav > I can see how worse it got. :P May be you downvoted. By the way can I know the purpose of array of checkbox? Because there is a better thing called simple_list_item_single_choice.

Answer (score 0):

To generate checkbox with in loop,you don't need to set globalize variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Utstyr.size(); i++) {
cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
......
}
```

instead of  above code you have to initialize like below.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Utstyr.size(); i++) {
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
    ......
    }
```

to Get selected check box you have to use following code

```
int childcount = checkbox_lay.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
      View v = checkbox_lay.getChildAt(i);

     if(v instanceof Checkbox){

    Checkbox ck=(Checkbox)v;
       boolean isSelected = ch.isChecked(); 
      }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you need reference to those checkboxes.
Creat an array of checkboxes and add it everytime you creat one,  and than you can get what you need from them ...